# Specific html tags are not displayed in the frontend

Tags: typo3, rte

My backend (RTE) shows me:

```
<p> <b>Header</b> Some text <a href="#">Link</a> </p>
```

But when I open my frontend in the browser and check the source code I get this:

```
<b>Header</b> Some Text Link
```

So I thought that maybe some html tags get deleted or not stored in the database. But when I reopen it in the backend (RTE):

```
<p> <b>Header</b> Some text <a href="#">Link</a> </p>
```

The tags are still there. So they only won't be displayed in the frontend.
How can I show the original code in the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the target of the link is not reachable?

TYPO3 checks links and if they are not accessable, it doesn't render the link.